# Instant Apps: Problem with using DialogFragments or AlertDialogs in Instant App on a specific device Xiaomi Redmi S2 (Android 8.1)

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, dialogfragment, xiaomi

I have been facing problems when using `DialogFragments` or `AlertDialogs` on **Xiaomi Redmi S2 (Android 8.1)** while deploying an instant app. For the rest of the devices that I have tested everything seems to be just fine.

The problem occurs when I get to call `DialogFragment()` or `AlertDialog` to open, it takes them about 4-5s to appear. When I look at logs, I see that every method (`onCreate()`,`onViewCreated()`) is executed on time, but the dialog appears with this huge lag!

**This problem disappears if I change my class that inherits DialogFragment() to inherit just Fragment(), but that is not what I need.**

Can anybody suggest where to look out for the problem?

Comment: is this lag also present on the xiaomi device if the app is just an installed-app?

Comment: No, it's working normally when the full app is installed.

Comment: You should file this to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/components/316045, provide a small sample code and a bugreport.

Comment: I have existing app on play store. So insta App will be implement on my existing app Or need to create another app to make insta app.